"inaccessible boot device" on Windows Server 2019 after Windows Update: known fixes?
Has anyone had an "inaccessible boot device" stop error on Windows Server 2019 after a failed Windows Update, and managed to get the server to boot again without restoring from a backup, snapshot, or a restore point?
Notes:

First-hand experience only please, answer only if you had this exact issue, were able to fix it without restoring anything, and believe the fix may apply to this scenario. (If asking the question this way is against SF rules or policies - please do not remove this condition and do not edit the question - rather, just hide the question. Thank you.)
This is a question similar to (but not the same as) "INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE on Windows Server 2019 after Windows update installation". The key difference is that in our case, the BCD table appears to be healthy, matching the partition table - see screenshots below.




Additional context:
Upon starting the VM, it does display the usual Windows boot UI with Windows logo and a spinning dots for about 30 seconds:

... then - "INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE" stop error:

It then reboots, does this once more (Windows logo, spinning dots, "INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE" stop error), and then into WinRE mode:

Even more context:

Windows Server 2019 VM on ESXi 7.03
refused to be patched in the last two monthly Windows Update cycles - "Windows couldn't apply updates, rolling back" - or something like that
my last attempt to patch with two 2024-08 Windows Update patches - resulted in "INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE" stop error after a reboot. This is unusual as we have other VMs that refuse to be patched in a similar way - yet this VM is the first one with this issue
the vmdk is fine (no errors), the file system is fine (disk checks, sfc /scannow all come back clear
I followed all the steps I could follow in "Advanced troubleshooting for Stop error 7B or Inaccessible_Boot_Device" MS KB article, and the steps in "INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE on Windows Server 2019 after Windows update installation" - still the same issue. (Some of the steps - I couldn't follow as, say, bootrec /rebuildbcd would result in "access denied" and some of the instructions appear to be invalid or missing necessary information.)
The "Reset This PC" option is unavailable: after choosing "Repair Your Computer" in "Advanced Boot Options", the VM goes into WinRE, and there isn't a recovery option other than using an external recovery image.
at this point, I am less worried about getting this particular VM to boot (it's not critical), and more - about what to do in similar situations going forward:

if the file system is good, the registry is good - then what does it take to repair the boot components so the server could boot again as it was before the failed update? (Yes, I know, "restore from snapshot / restore point / most recent backup" - yah, with you here - asking a different question here, thank you.)
how to find out exactly what and where something is failing during the boot process?


hope this is enough context; if not - please let me know!

Thanks!

What about list partition for disk 0? That is what the boot loader is complaining about.

thanks! added the screenshot of list partition output to the question

Expand the disk to 300GB. We had this same issue where the updates couldn't install due to lack of space needed.

thanks Eric - 120GB used out of 200GB in the partition - i.e. 60% used, 40% free - so this unlikely to be the case - but I'll try it when I have a chance (no promises, several fires to fight at the moment)
